# Is there a known reason for the position of the stress in "concupisc-" words in English?

Tags: english, phonology, etymology, latin, stress

The words *concúpiscent, concúpiscence, concúpiscible* seem to be irregularly stressed (at least, according to their dictionary pronunciations; regularized pronunciations apparently have been heard "in the wild") when compared to words like *reminíscent(-ce), dehíscent(-ce), oblivíscible, immíscible, permíscible,* not to mention a lot of other words with *-éscent*(*-ce*).

I found this exception mentioned in the fourth edition of [John Walker's "Critical Pronouncing Dictionary"](https://books.google.com/books?id=LeOD_sYogbsC&pg=PA67&lpg=PA67&dq=concupiscence%20stress%20syllable&source=bl&ots=kxe05z3n3M&sig=-pP5SHOVPtEk8p4XF2Cd1JJV14E&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjS1qDYrbfTAhVs54MKHaUjCZ0Q6AEIMTAD#v=onepage&q=concupiscence%20stress%20syllable&f=false) (1846), but there is no explanation given. The Oxford English Dictionary entries for these three words also don't explain the pronunciation.

Has anyone attempted to do so?

---

I tried to think of possible reasons, and the only thing I could come up with is possible stress shift from an original Middle English *concupiscént/concupiscénce* (taken from the stress in French or in Latin *concupiscentia*) via the somewhat common pattern of putting secondary stress on alternating syllables. Whereas, presumably, the other *-scent/-scence* words either came into English at a later period, when word-final stress was no longer common, or their pronunciation was remodeled for some reason while that of *concupiscence* etc. was not.

The OED's earliest citation is "c1340," spelled "concupyscens" which does seem earlier than the first OED citation for "adolescence" ("?a1425") or "pubescence" (?a1425). I also wasn't able to find any earlier attested use of an "-escence" word in the  [Middle English Dictionary quotations](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/m/mec/med-idx?size=First+100&type=headword&q1=*scence&rgxp=constrained).

Even if nobody knows about these specific words, I would appreciate any more general information on the stress patterns of words ending in *-ence* or *-ance* in Middle English, and how they may have changed in the development to present-day English.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand Walker, he's saying the regular case is words like "quiESCence", with accent on the penult.  If "concupiscence" were stressed on the penult, it would be pronounced "concuPISSence", which sounds vaguely obscene.

Comment: Interesting. I did not think about obscenity avoidance, but this does seem to play a role in the pronunciation of some words, such as *fuchsia, Pisces,* and *piscine,* so it seems plausible it could have affected this word.

Comment: It had never occurred to me to put the stress anywhere but the penult. It's quite possible that I've never heard anybody pronounce them.

Comment: _Piston_ and _pistol_ are perfectly cromulent English words .

Comment: Cromulent or not, technical terms tend to evolve away from potential taboo syllables. That's why the Sushitna river was renamed the Susitna. Those pesky penults.

Answer (score 2):

This is more of a bit of musing than a proper answer, but it could be the reason that at least the first two have this seemingly irregular stress pattern.

*Concúpiscent* and *concúpiscence* don't sound oddly stressed to me at all—in fact they sound perfectly acceptable and normal, despite the fact that I'm quite sure I've never heard anyone say either word. *Concúpiscible*, on the other hand, sounds downright bizarre.

Like you, I could find no other parallel for an *-Vscence/-Vscibility* word having the stress on the syllable before the -sc-, so it puzzled me that I find *concúpiscent/-ce* so normal-sounding.

I tried to figure out what pattern made *-úpiscent* sound perfectly normal—and it finally hit me: *magnificent* and its ilk!

The *-ficent* suffix is etymologically unrelated, of course (apart from stemming from Latin participles), but it is phonetically /ˡVCɪsənt/ with antepaenultimate stress, just like what we find in *concupiscent*. And unlike more closely related word like *reminiscent* and *dehiscent*, there's no base verb **concupisce* to show where the stress should go.

So I would theorise that perhaps *concupiscent/-ce*, wherever the stress originally lay, may have retracted its stress due to phonetic similarity with words in *-ficent*.

That doesn't account for *concupiscible*, of course, and I'll admit that I'm stumped there. Looking through a reverse dictionary I cannot find a single other word ending in *-cible* that has preantepaenultimate stress—it seems to be totally irregular and counter to all logic.